# How to install Ubuntu on broken computer

Tags: system-installation

I have an older laptop that I want to install Ubuntu on. I've burned the iso to a DVD and tried to boot from this, but it always ask for a passcode to unencrypt the hard drive (I encrypted the whole drive when I installed Ubuntu on it a long time ago), and then it gives the following error and freezes: drm_kms_helper panic.

Is there any way I can just completely wipe the hard drive and start over with a new version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to wipe the hard disk in your situation is probably to remove it from the machine, connect it to another (you can get a test connector for about $15 that will connect any IDE or SATA drive to a USB port), and use a partition editor there to create a new partition table, followed by building new partitions etc.

If you could get the laptop to boot to the DVD, you *should* be able to do that from the Live CD without removing the hard disk -- I suspect there's a problem with your burned DVD.  Try a USB key, or a previously known-good CD/DVD with another Linux Live OS on it.